# Can Table Layout have both horizontal and vertical scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout, android-scrollview

Hi i created a Table Layout with normal Scroll view, I want it to scroll both vertical and horizontal. In XML is it possible or if there is any other solution to solve as my text is going out of table once it exceeds the length and it makes the table layout bigger and moves oout of the device.

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearImag">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </LinearLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/lead_table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bgbtn"
                    android:text="Lead ID"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
        </TableLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_add"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/add" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_data"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of normal scroll view , use horizontal scroll view like

```
<Layout>
 <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/horizontalView" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip">
<TableLayout>
    // child views...
</TableLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</Layout>
```

Hope this will solve your problem :-)